# What is the area of the shaded region if $AB=120$?

Tags: geometry, area, pythagorean-triples

What is the area of the blue region if $AB=120$.

I can only think in $\triangle OAB$ (O b being the low left point and the triangle is right) I can use Pythagoras which involves $120$, radius $r$ of the arc and diameter $d$ of the circle but I'm stuck there.

$$r^2=d^2+120^2$$

I know the area we are looking for is $$\frac{1}{4}\pi r^2 - \pi \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2$$

[image]

Comment: If the radius of the small circle is $r$, what is the radius of the large circular arc?

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.  See also the **Edit-Images** section of the article.

Comment: Keep going like you have been and you'll have solved it.

Comment: Oh boy its solving for d^2 in the first one and then substituting below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were correct in your first equation. The diagram below shows this at a glance.
Now we show that the area is the large quarter circle minus the small circle.
\begin{align*}
A&=\dfrac{\pi R^2}{4}-\pi r^2= \dfrac{\pi \big((2r)^2+120^2\big)}{4}-\pi r^2\\\\
&=\big(\pi r^2 + 3600\pi\big)-\pi r^2\\\\
&=3600\pi
\end{align*}

[image]

Comment: @peterwhy I think my diagram stands on its own given the label below it. The only things that matter are A and I and r and 120. Do you disagree that the solution is now easy to see?

Comment: No, the solution have been easy to see; I just thought that it's unnecessary to rename points using existing names. And as you mentioned the label in the diagram, some would prefer to [repeat that label as text](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/89922) too.

Comment: But keep in mind that this can't be a general solution unless some assumption about $R$ is made: if $R$ is "large" compared to $120$ the white circle will extend the quarter circle ...

Comment: @Michael Hoppe  You are correct. I think I’ll look into a solution to that offline.